# Como deixar as td das tabelas aumentando ou diminuindo automaticamente o tamanho conforme a quantidade de caracteres?

Tags: html, css

Como deixar as `td` da `table` aumentando ou diminuindo automaticamente o tamanho conforme a quantidade de caracteres? Para evitar que o texto acabe quebrando linha?

Comment: Pode ser com Flex ou tem que ser com Table mesmo? O que vc já tem de código?

Comment: Eu estou usando table mesmo. Tem como?

Comment: Tem sim, vc pode usar valores em % na Table, mas não estou entendendo direito o que vc quer fazer. O texto não pode quebrar nunca? Tem que ser sempre em uma linha só? Por isso te pedi o código do que vc já tem, ou pelo menos uma imagem de como vc quer que fique. Com Flex e Divs é possível fazer tb.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi muito bem, mas pra que não haja quebra de linhas, basta definir a propriedade [white-space](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) do *CSS* como `nowrap`:

```css
table tr > th,
table tr > td
{
  padding: 10px;
  border: #bbb 1px solid;
}

tr > td:first-child
{
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Texto sem quebrar</th>
      <th>Texto comum</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto</td>
      <td>Texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```